# Building umlet custom elements

Tags: umlet

I am trying to do a collaboration diagram in umlet, but there isn't a palette element to do so.  So I thought I'd create one.  Easier said than done!  I am able to define the class element of the diagram, but am unable to define the arrows that define the flow of the collaboration.

I've tried adding a drawline statement to the code window, but it is undefined in umlet custom element implementation.

```
    //Modify the code below to define the element's behavior.
    //
    //Example:  Change the line
    //  y += printCenter(textline,y);
    //to
    //  y += 2*printCenter(textline,y);
    //and observe the element preview.

    int y=textHeight();

    drawRectangle(0,0,100,35);
    drawRectangle(0,150,100,35);
    //drawline(10,35,10,115);


    for(String textline : textlines) {
        y += printCenter(textline,y);
    }
```

The expected result should be two class elements and two arrows denoting the flow of the collaboration.

[image: Expected Result]

I've gotten this far, but I am unable to save it to the custom elements palette.

Answer (score 0):

Welllll, my bad!  It turns out that you can use the regular palette elements to construct the diagram and then save it to umlet's palettes directory.